# Exclude regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this line take a regex
And match the value from response

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(" + elem.get("urlRegex").getAsString() + ")").matcher(response);
```

And here is the `elem.get("urlRegex").getAsString()`

```
https?://(www\.)?facebook\.com/(?!(i|business|legal|dialog|sharer|share\.phpr|tr|business|platform|help|ads|policies|selfxss|audiencenetwork)$)([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]|(\.))+
```

And response is https response

This regex should match anything like

> https://www.facebook.com/testaksdflasfjasldf

> https://www.facebook.com/rqwerpoiqwern

> https://www.facebook.com/gbjkdasjasdfuiew

And it shouldn't match anything like

> https://www.facebook.com/i

> https://www.facebook.com/business

> https://www.facebook.com/legal

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer

But it does match both and the exclude doesn't work

I did debug it on regex101 but it works

Edit 1:

I did remove `$` from exclude and it works
But because there is `i` in the exclude group
The regex will not match anything like
`https://www.facebook.com/intel`
`https://www.facebook.com/inscanasdas`
`https://www.facebook.com/iasdasdasd`

Edit 2:

I did test the smiler of my code with this regex on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/
Regex works

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your regex:

1. Escaping only needs a single backslash, not two.
2. All characters with special meaning in regex (like `?`, `(`, `)`, `.`) need to be escaped.
3. The last part of your regex was wrong.

Use this:

`https\?://\(www\.\)\?facebook\.com/(?!(i|business|legal|dialog|sharer|share\.phpr|tr|business|platform|help|ads|policies|selfxss|audiencenetwork)$)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tzLjXf/1)

Comment: I am very sorry 
Because i saved it in json file i add double backslash
And i did copy the regex from the json to here directly

Comment: @shanesontr There are other issues in your regex which I've fixed. Take a close look.

Comment: Sorry again 
I did add `https?://(www.)?` in the question result match 
For remove the complexity from the question and regex
But i meant to match 'https://www.facebook.com/'
Not `https\?://\(www\.\)\?` as string

Comment: @shanesontr Edit your question to include the correct details.